# How can I capture whether an error occurred in Rust's swap_with_slice() vec method?

Tags: error-handling, rust

The documentation tells me that the `swap_with_slice()` method can potentially panic if the slices are of two different lengths. I am writing a parser which deals with data coming across TCP. My encoding scheme is such that the following *should* never panic, unless it is a malformed request. In this case, I don't want my programme to crash, but instead handle the error. How do I capture whether `swap_with_slice` panics or not? Since it itself does not return a Result?

```
let mut bytes_id = [0; 16];
bytes_id.swap_with_slice(&mut self.raw_bytes[Headers::MessageLength as usize..Headers::Data as usize]);
```

Comment: If "method can potentially panic if the slices are of two different lengths" then obvious solution to avoid panic is to check sizes of slices before calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
let result = std::panic::catch_unwind(|| <expected_to_panic_operation_here>);
```